# QuickLook is not working with mac OS High Sierra 10.13.3

Tags: high-sierra, quicklook-plugin

I installed quick look plugin  StringsFile.qlgenerator and I moved it the the following path /Library/QuickLook as illustrated in https://blog.timac.org/2014/0325-quicklook-plugin-to-preview-strings-files/ 
Yet, it is not working. The files that I am trying to use show are txt files .bib. 
Any idea how to fix that. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your .bib file is like my simple example from https://www.latex-tutorial.com/tutorials/bibtex/#bib-file I'd say you rather want a general plain text QuickLook-plugin (aka qlgenerator), or a specific .bib one.

There might be others but I don't mind suggesting [QLStephen](https://whomwah.github.io/qlstephen/) that has been around and working fine for a long time and nicely previewed both my .bib example file and a .strings one i found; not trying to install the QL-plugin you linked; though, to verify how it works, I did download the linked plugin's source and saw its package `Contents/Info.plist` (showable by context menu click in Finder) having `CFBundleDocumentTypes` UTI `com.apple.xcode.strings-text` whereas QLStephen uses an extremely general fallback UTI of `public.data` to preview anything not picked up by any other plugin.

One could try to just modify the linked .qlgenerator's `Contents/Info.plist` to include something about .bib extension or UTI but that would require extending the scope to referencing 
[developer documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Articles/RegisteringtheFileTypesYourAppSupports.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010411-SW1).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I installed QLStephen, yet still has the same problem. I am wondering if QLStephen should work without any modification for Info.plist. Any thoughts. Thanks again.

Comment: hm, did you also do the last installation instruction "• Execute the command qlmanage -r in the Terminal - or restart the machine" from your link? I also see https://whomwah.github.io/qlstephen/ and https://github.com/whomwah/qlstephen seem to link different versions, and checking here i see i'm currently using version 1.3.1 (where i only find 1.3 on github.com and don't know where i got mine), which version did you install?

Comment: Thanks, I installed version 1.4.4 https://github.com/whomwah/qlstephen/releases and run qlmanage -r, yet still no progress.

Comment: dang.. i would `open /Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app` and copy/paste `mdls -name kMDItemContentTypeTree ` with a space after, then drag and drop the file and hit enter..
Another thing to try in Terminal is `qlmanage -d1 -p ` w/ space, drag & drop and enter to see if it says anything about what is happening..

Comment: oops  sorry, I wasn't clear I meant you to drag and drop your .bib file - feel free to redact anything you think could be personal (eg Documents paths). You might as well try to delete the comments about the QLStephen.qlgenerator. But at least we've confirmed working terminal functionality, eheh  cheers